# Kurtosis is invariant for linear transformation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I was told that the Kurtosis
$$\gamma_4 = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mu)^4]}{\sigma^4}$$
is invariant for linear transformation.

But when I plug in $Y = aX+b$, I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[(aX+b-a\mu-b)^4]}{Var(aX+b)^4}=\frac{a^4\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^4]}{a^{2\cdot 4}Var(X)^4} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^4]}{a^{2}Var(X)^4}
\end{align*}
which is clearly not invariant.

I'm not sure what went wrong. I used $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(aX)=a\mathbb{E}(X)$

Comment: $\sigma = \sqrt{\text{Var}(X)}$. (Btw. $\frac{a^4}{a^{2\cdot4}} = \frac{1}{a^4}$)

Comment: @GáborPálovics Gigantic Facepalm. Thanks!